# Is a zero-dimensional system always consistent?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Given a system of polynomial equations in several unknowns which is known to be zero-dimensional, the system always has a solution? I think this is not true but I have read that a necessary and sufficient condition for a system to be consistent is that the Gröbner basis is (1). However, there exist systems with a Gröbner basis other than (1) that are consistent. I suppose the zero-dimensionality property only upper limits the number of solutions, but it is still possible to have 0 solutions. Is this true?

Comment: Are you working over an algebraically closed field?  Some of this is true by definition/convention.  For example, the empty set is negative dimensional, so $0$-dimensional does indeed mean there's a solution.

Comment: I was trying to work on the reals and as you point out Groebner's method works on an algebraically closed field such as the complex field. Then the solutions in general are complex.